# Polymorphic model in mongodb with nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, polymorphism

I am currently working on a projet that require a very high versatility in the way I deal with the data storage. Let's say that the principle is that the user can define a customized model and then fill the database with data based on the model he defined.

My solution so far is that i save the definition of the model in a MongoDB collection, and then generate a model from it with a DocumentFactory.

```
DocumentFactory: function(description) {

    var attributes = {};

    description.forEach(function(element, index){
        attributes[element.name] = {
            type: "string",
            required: true
        };
    });

    var model = mongoose.Schema(attributes);

    return mongoose.model('Meta', model);;
}
```

My problem is that i can define the "MetaModel" only once, after i'll catch an error:
**OverwriteModelError: Cannot overwrite `Meta` model once compiled**

Actually, the model is compiled by MongoDB once and for all. I didn't find a way to overwrite it.

I see 2 solutions:

1. Find a way to define a model without compiling it. This solution might be the best, so i can use the mongo validation system.
2. Create a unique name for model, but it seems to be a very bad solution so i'll possibly have thousands of models.

Any idea ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I guess your first solution, or the one you want to do is not very elegant, because basically you want to use one collection with different models in it. Which does not make really sense. At this point forget about using an ORM and build your own to make this mess.

I would choose the second solution or maybe, mongodb is not what you need here. You could explain better your case and we could try to help you out to find a better solution maybe.